# Juntar listas sem repetir

Tags: c#, .net, lista

Tenho duas listas:

[image: Listas]
.

Queria uma forma de juntar as duas listas de forma aleatória sem repetir letras e números na mesma letra em `C#`, por exemplo:

[image: Listas Concatenadas]

Comment: Sua pergunta não parece fazer sentido pra mim. Principalmente porque a segunda imagem é igual a primeira, a diferença é que os itens estão embaralhados.

Comment: Você precisa explicar direito o que quer fazer, quais são as listas que você tem? E qual o resultado esperado?

Comment: Exatamente isso "juntar as duas listas de forma aleatória sem repetir letras e números na mesma letra", as letras estão aleatórias e não há repetição de números em letras, exemplo: A = 999 e A = 999

Comment: Mas você não "**juntou**" absolutamente nada. Por favor, responda o que eu perguntei: quais são as listas que você tem? E qual o resultado esperado?

Answer (score 1):

[Use o LINQ](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.union?view=netcore-3.1):

```
var lista3 = lista1.Union(lista2).ToList();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Linq/Union.cs).

Comment: Amigo, este comando apenas une as listas, não verifica items repetidos. Agradeço a intenção.

Comment: Não é o que está escrito na documentação. Se você tivesse colocado seu código eu teria usado como exemplo e mostrado que faz o que deseja.

Comment: @bigown Eu acho que esta pergunta deveria ser fechada

Comment: @LINQ tá com cara.